# Serially execute db.all function in meteor node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, meteor

I have the following code.

```
  sqlite3 = Npm.require("sqlite3").verbose()
  db = new sqlite3.Database("sqlSample.db")

  console.log "DB connection made"

  db.serialize ->
    db.run "CREATE TABLE CarDetails(make TEXT)"

    stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO CarDetails VALUES (?)")
    i = 0
    while i < 10
      stmt.run "Item #" + i
      i++
    stmt.finalize()

    console.log "Values inserted into DB"

    db.all "SELECT rowid AS id, make FROM CarDetails", (err, rows) ->
      console.log rows

  console.log "Closing the DB connection"

  db.close()
```

The output in console when this code is executed in server startup of meteor is

```
DB connection made
Values inserted into DB
Closing the DB connection
[ { id: 1, make: 'Item #0' },
   { id: 2, make: 'Item #1' },
   { id: 3, make: 'Item #2' },
   { id: 4, make: 'Item #3' },
   { id: 5, make: 'Item #4' },
   { id: 6, make: 'Item #5' },
   { id: 7, make: 'Item #6' },
   { id: 8, make: 'Item #7' },
   { id: 9, make: 'Item #8' },
   { id: 10, make: 'Item #9' } ]
```

Here the 'Closing the DB connection' is printed before the query results are printed (I know the reason for this). What I want to know is how the code has to be modified so that the 'Closing the DB connection' is printed only after the rows value are printed.

I tried to use

```
rows = db.all "SELECT rowid AS id, make FROM CarDetails"
console.log rows
```

But the output got is

```
DB connection made
Values inserted into DB
{ open: false,
 filename: 'sqlSample.db',
 mode: 65542 }
Closing the DB connection
```

Here it is executed in the desired sequence but instead of result set I am getting some other json object in rows.

Please tell me what is the problem with this or suggest any other approach to run the complete code serially. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control asynchronous execution flow in node.js/meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831066/control-asynchronous-execution-flow-in-node-js-meteor)

Comment: @Chris - This question is not duplicate. This question is about how to execute db.all serially. The one which you are referring is on how to return value correctly while using 'http-methods' atmosphere package. I have used the same sample code from node-sqlite3 online wiki in both questions which might have confused you that the questions are duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Meteor._wrapAsync to execute db.all serially. Please note that this is against the 'node-sqlite3' purpose of asynchronous non-blocking execution.

```
dbAllSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(db.all.bind(db))
rows = dbAllSync("SELECT rowid AS id, make FROM CarDetails")
console.log rows
```

Pass the asynchronous function name as parameter the _wrapAsync method. If the function has to be executed in some object's context, add '.bind' to the method name and specify the object as it's parameter. Here 'all' method has to be called in context of 'db' object. The type of dbAllSync is Function. Use it to execute the asynchronous 'db.all' synchronously by passing parameters to it.

Use the following references if you want to know more about _wrapAsync method.

- https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/Ww3rQrHJo8FLgK7FF
- http://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html