# Control asynchronous execution flow in node.js/meteor

Tags: node.js, sqlite, meteor

I am using a meteorite application with 'http-methods' package from atmosphere and 'node-sqlite3' package from npm. Consider the flowing code.

```
var results = null;
HTTP.methods({
    'list': function(data) {
      var sqlite3 = Npm.require('sqlite3').verbose();
      var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

      db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
        }
        stmt.finalize();

        db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, rows) {
            console.log(rows);
            results = rows;
        });
      });

      console.log("Closing DB");
      db.close();

      console.log("Sending back response");
      console.log(results);

      return results;
    }
  });
```

Here using domain/list the above function is invoked. I want to return the resultSet as response to the request. But instead of it 'null' is been returned. The output from the console is given below.

```
I20131229-23:50:20.092(1)? Closing DB
I20131229-23:50:20.113(1)? Sending back response
I20131229-23:50:20.117(1)? null
I20131229-23:50:20.172(1)? [ { id: 1, info: 'Ipsum 0' },
I20131229-23:50:20.181(1)?   { id: 2, info: 'Ipsum 1' },
I20131229-23:50:20.182(1)?   { id: 3, info: 'Ipsum 2' },
I20131229-23:50:20.183(1)?   { id: 4, info: 'Ipsum 3' },
I20131229-23:50:20.199(1)?   { id: 5, info: 'Ipsum 4' },
I20131229-23:50:20.199(1)?   { id: 6, info: 'Ipsum 5' },
I20131229-23:50:20.199(1)?   { id: 7, info: 'Ipsum 6' },
I20131229-23:50:20.202(1)?   { id: 8, info: 'Ipsum 7' },
I20131229-23:50:20.202(1)?   { id: 9, info: 'Ipsum 8' },
I20131229-23:50:20.203(1)?   { id: 10, info: 'Ipsum 9' } ]
```

Please suggest a appropriate solution to the problem.

Note: The code given is a synonymous of the actual one. Please let me know if you want to know more details.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You are outputting 'results' before the db callback.  You also close the db connection pretty much as soon as you make your query.  I can guess that the db module finishes the query before closing though, as it does eventually output the rows returned.

You'll want to put the close and return in the callback.

```
db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    results = rows;

    db.close();
    callback(results);
});
```

EDIT:

Here's a better example, use a callback instead of return:

```
var results = null;
HTTP.methods({
'list': function(data, callback) {
  var sqlite3 = Npm.require('sqlite3').verbose();
  var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

  db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }
    stmt.finalize();

    db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        results = rows;

        db.close();            

        // this returns the data in a callback function
        callback(results);
    });
  });

  // this will return 'results' before the query returns any results
  // return results;
}
});
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't works. 'db.all' call initiates a new parallel/asynchronous execution. While the query results is being fetched in one execution flow, empty response is being send back to the client. (Everything inside the callback of 'db.all' is executed in one thread and the remaining code in the main thread). I need some mechanism to stop execution of main thread until the other thread is finished or some mechanism to make 'db.all' execute in same thread rather than in new one.

Comment: Your solution didn't solve the issue. Still the response is returning back as null.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by putting a delay method of javascript which halts the execution for specified amount of time. you can stop the execution for few second and your problem will be solved.